# Where do I find Application cursor files in MacOS?

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, finalcut

I'm specifically looking to find the files for the tool cursors in Final Cut Pro X.
Any help would be great thanks.

[image: Cursor Screenshot]

Comment: Is the question still actual?

Answer (score 0):

These cursors don't look like system cursors, so they are the custom ones.

You can look at the system cursors ("pointers") here: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/pointers-in-macos-mh35695/mac

The custom images should be located in `Final Cut Pro X.app/Contents/Resources` - just right-mouse-click on your `Final Cut Pro X.app`, select `Show Package Contents`, then navigate to `Resources` folder.

There should be a lot on `png` icons.

Comment: Didn't find any in there. They must be hidden somewhere